# HFS partition mounting read-only

Tags: linux, macos, mount, hfs

I have an external Western Digital Hard drive with two HFS partitions with journaling disabled.

When I connect it to a computer running Linux (Debian or Ubuntu), frequently both partitions are mounted read-only. In the past, mounting them on my Macbook and executing the command to disable the journaling often worked (even though it would tell me that journaling was already disabled) but I would love to have a solution which works every time.

Thanks!

Edit: In light of Chris Johnsen's comment below - my question is how to mount the filesystem read+write on Linux since it is not automatically doing so itself

Comment: There was no actual question in your question. Are we to infer that you expect your HFS (probably HFS+?) filesystems to be mounted read+write on Linux?

Comment: Well my question was how to mount the filesystem read+write on Linux since it is not automatically doing so itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask Linux to remount the partition read-write with this command (replace hdb2 as appropriate):

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/hdb2
```

Of course, this may or may not fix your problem :)